# Displaying placeholder HTML when Javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, html

I need to display a banner in a my HTML file when java script is disabled as in stackoverflow site. In stackoverflow site, it is displayed a red banner when java script is disabled. It is good to whole HTML page goes little bit down and display a red message as in this stackoverflow site when JS is disabled. Can any one help me to do this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: `<noscript>` does not meant for that ?

Comment: Yes it is. View the source of this page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's still the way to do it, but `noscript` works for that.

```
<noscript>Javascript is disabled</noscript>
```

So I suppose that a specific `div` inside the `noscript` should do the job.

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>noscript test</title>
                <style>
                        #nojs {
                                top: 0px;
                                width: 100%;
                                position: absolute;
                                background-color: red;
                                color: white;
                                border-bottom: solid 5px black;
                        }
                </style>

        </head>

        <body>

        <noscript><div id="nojs">You should enable javascript!!</div></noscript>

        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Aif, I have used that noscript tag. But I want to display that message as in this site on the top of the page. For that, where I should keep that this tag? Within head? I also wanted to slide the whole page little bit down and display the message. I am new to HTML. Please give any ideas about it..

Comment: @vish: added an html sample that seems to do the job. The css part is not as intended but it gives you a better idea.

Comment: Hi Aif,Thank you very much for sample.. That works nice.=) But what should I do for shift down header for make space for this message..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Use `<noscript>` tag:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript

Answer (score 0):

Display the banner and hide it with JavaScript. Thus it is shown if JavaScript is not enabled!

For example

```
<img src="myimage.gif" id="myImage" />

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("myImage").style.display="none";
}

</script>
```

Comment: And what if JavaScript is enabled but CSS is not?

Comment: A good point however the question asked by vish is "Displaying placeholder HTML when Javascript is disabled" not "Displaying placeholder HTML when Javascript is enabled and CSS is not". I see your point though, <noscript> is the safer solution

Comment: if you wish to use JavaScript to prevent some content from appearing, then the safe solution is to remove the element from the document tree, not just set its style. It takes a little more code, and this makes the `<noscript>` approach so tempting.

Comment: I agree... with my solution above FOUC could be an issue!